# TYPO3 how to inject objectManager in hook?

Tags: dependency-injection, typo3, hook, typo3-8.x

Maybe it's just simple, but I can't figure it out.

TYPO3 8.7: I am programming a small hook: if a certain condition is met I want to send an email. Therefore I need the standalone view for the email template. But for the standalone view I need the object manager:

```
/** @var \TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView $emailView
$emailView = $this->objectManager->get('TYPO3\\CMS\\Fluid\\View\\StandaloneView');
```

At the beginning of my class I tried to inject the objectManager:

```
/**
 * @var \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface
 */
protected $objectManager;

/**
 * @param \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager
 * @internal
 */
public function injectObjectManager(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManagerInterface $objectManager)
{
    $this->objectManager = $objectManager;
}
```

But it does not work: I run into an error: the objectManager is a null object. Which obviously means that the injection mechanism is not present in the hook.

How can this be achieved then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extbase Dependency Injection is not available in hooks, so you have to create instances of objects yourself.

```
$standaloneView = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager::class)
->get(TYPO3\CMS\Fluid\View\StandaloneView::class);
```

Comment: Seems logic, but when I enter this code I run into an "Oops, an error occurred!".

Comment: If I separate this line in two lines setting the objectManager first and then the standAloneView with `$objectManager->get()`, it works. (?!?)